# Ruby on Rails error - NoMethodError in Statuses#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error **NoMethodError in Statuses#new** when I try to view a page in my app after I add the form field... I'm new to ruby on rails so am keen to be able to fully understand this...

```
<%= f.input :user_id %>
```

Here is the full error message:

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#new

Showing /Users/danlee/Projects/treebook/app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `user_id' for #<Status:0x007feb53cdd138>
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:     </div>
12:   <% end %>
13: 
14:   <%= f.input :user_id %>
15:   <%= f.input :content %>
16:   <div class="form-actions">
17:     <%= f.button :submit %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/statuses/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/danlee/Projects/treebook

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_statuses__form_html_erb__4012047659275744874_70324335923840'
app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_statuses__form_html_erb__4012047659275744874_70324335923840'
app/views/statuses/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_statuses_new_html_erb___64465850179705865_70324349236340'
app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:29:in `new'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Github repository for the app is here too: https://github.com/pixeljugglerdan/treebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't added the :user_id column to your statuses. This file isn't running any code in the #change method: https://github.com/pixeljugglerdan/treebook/blob/master/db/migrate/20120911210237_add_user_id_to_statuses.rb

You'll probably want to re-run the migration with something like:

```
class AddUserIdToStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :statuses, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```